# Defining database independent JPA object uid

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, datanucleus

It turns out that the following example works when using mysql 5.x, however it doesn't when using an oracle 10g database.

Is there a way to define a unique identifier field that is independent of the database technology?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private long id;
```

I have tested this in hibernate and the following exception occurs only when using Oracle:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Dialect does not support identity key generation
```

Comment: Why don't you use `GenerationType.AUTO` so that the provider will choose the optimal strategy depending on the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched using `GenerationType.AUTO` and it does appear to be the better option. It allows the JPA implementation to choose whatever is best for the data storage system you are using.

Comment: The catch with GenerationType.AUTO is that the provider needs to have database permissions to create a table or sequence if it chooses either of those strategies. Normally this is a privileged operation restricted to the DBA. In this case you'll need to ensure the persistent resource is created before the AUTO strategy is able to function.

Answer (score 4):

Using a database table is a portable way to generate identifiers.

The simplest way to use a table to generate identifiers is to specify `TABLE` as the generation strategy:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name="id")
private long id;
```

The provider will create the default table if you're using schema generation; if not, you must specify an existing table:

```
@TableGenerator(name="InvTab",
    table="ID_GEN",
    pkColumnName="ID_NAME",
    valueColumnName="ID_VAL",
    pkColumnValue="INV_GEN")
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="InvTab")
@Column(name="id")
private long id;
```

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/howto/id-generation.html#table