# Hibernate IdentityColumnSupportImpl Does Not Support Identity Key Generation

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two different data sources in spring boot project. One of the datasource's schema name is fraud and the other one is test. When I try to insert an object into the table, I am getting an error such as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.dialect.identity.IdentityColumnSupportImpl does not support identity key generation
```

I tried this to solve my problem

[org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect does not support identity key generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009042/org-hibernate-dialect-oracledialect-does-not-support-identity-key-generation)

But this one gives an error such as

```
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

Thanks

## CONTROLLER

```
            if (channel.isAnyConvertionFailed()) {
                FraudChannelException fce = new FraudChannelException(/*Params*/);
                fraudChannelExceptionRepository.save(fce);
            }

            //Check if any mandatory fields are empty
            if (/*condition*/){
                FraudChannelException fce = new FraudChannelException(/*Params*/);
                fraudChannelExceptionRepository.save(fce);

                return ExceptionConfiguration.handleMissingFieldError(message);
            }
```

## REPOSITORY

```
@Repository
public interface FraudChannelExceptionRepository extends CrudRepository<FraudChannelException, Integer> {

}
```

## ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Table(name="fraud_channel_exceptions", schema = "fraud")
public class FraudChannelException implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    //more fields

    public FraudChannelException(/*PARAMS*/) {
        //init something
    }

    public FraudChannelException(/*PARAMS*/) {
        //init something
    }

    public FraudChannelException(/*PARAMS*/) {
        //init something
    }

    public FraudChannelException() {
    }

    //Getter Setter
}
```

## CONFIG

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ykb.frd.fraudcore.schema.fraud.repo",entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager",transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class FraudConfig{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.ykb.frd.fraudcore.schema.fraud.domain");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource= new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("fraud.datasource.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("fraud.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("fraud.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("fraud.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager= new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

## APPLICATION.PROPERTIES

```
# EBNKTST - NDVLIVE
ndvlive.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//URL
ndvlive.datasource.username=//USERNAME
ndvlive.datasource.password=//PASSWORD
ndvlive.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

# EBNKDEV - FRAUD
fraud.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//URL
fraud.datasource.username=//USERNAME
fraud.datasource.password=//PASSWORD
fraud.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate expects from underlying database to provide an auto increment feature for a given property, in your case it's `id`. IOW, Oracle(your case) should support auto increment feature for a field. Oracle started to provide auto increment feature with [12c version](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA109) and, as your version is less, you get that exception .